# preg_match for subject and body of email

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to extract subject/body of an email message generated by a form in Joomla.
I am using some tags for defining different subjects/body for each language, like:

```
{lang en}English Text{/lang}
{lang it}Italian Text{/lang}
{lang fr}French Text{/lang}
```

I have the following code for striping Text from Subjects in different languages:

```
$msgSubject = $template->subject;           
    if ($language=='it-IT')
    {                                               
    preg_match('~{lang it}([^{]*){/lang}~i', $msgSubject, $match);
    $msgSubject=($match[1]);
    }
    elseif ($language=='en-GB')
    {
    preg_match('~{lang en}([^{]*){/lang}~i', $msgSubject, $match);
    $msgSubject=($match[1]);
    }
```

and so on for other languages.
It works perfectly for the subjects of the emails, which is just plain text.
If I do the same on the Body, wich is a string containing HTML elemnes like p and br, and so on, it doesn't work....
Code sample:

```
$msgBody = $template->body;

                    if ($language=='it-IT')
                    {
                    preg_match('~{lang it}([^{]*){/lang}~i', $msgBody, $match);
                    $msgBody=($match[1]);

                    }
                     elseif ($language=='en-GB')
                    {
                    preg_match('~{lang en}([^{]*){/lang}~i', $msgBody, $match);
                    $msgBody=($match[1]);
                    }
```

it simply outputs nothing. What should I change in the preg_match function to avoid mass with HTML tags?

Comment: Can you check var_dump($msgBody) before if statement? I tested your code is working with html tags.

Comment: I tested it too and it looks like it's working. I will try to inspect the line of html code that 's generated in the body....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on preg_match_all
Is this what you want? Works for me..

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fkB

Edit:
If you do like this:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fkF
You capture the language too and you don't need the ifs.

Comment: I see that i missed to escape the last }. It works but it should be escaped to make sure it always work.

Comment: actually, it works on the preg_match test

see my actual line of html

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fkH

Comment: @Antonio accept the answer then ;-) but as I did in the second example you can get the language too if that is needed. Or if it's not needed then you still don't need a if for each language.  The reason I used preg_match_all was to show you it works on all languages and all (maybe) html tags.

Comment: @Antonio you are not going to accept or even upvote the answers of those who helped you? Shitty attitude...

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your code and it is working fine with html code also. But i think  that $msgBody containing multiple tags that you are using with joomla.
so you should use below code

```
preg_match_all('~{lang it}([^{]*){/lang}~i', $msgBody, $match);
```

because preg_match match only first occurance.

Comment: Thats's definitely something inside Joomla/Component tags. There are some other curly brackets in the HTML (used by a component as placeholders). If I remove the curly brackets it works OK....